# Terraform data source of an existing S3 bucket fails plan stage attempting a GetBucketWebsite request which returns NoSuchWebsiteConfiguration

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to use a data source of an existing S3 bucket like this:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "src-config-bucket" {
bucket = "single-word-name" }
```

And Terraform always fails the plan stage with the message:

```
Error: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
    status code: 403, request id: XXXXX
```

The requests failing can be viewed with the following info in the results:

```
{
"eventVersion": "1.08",
"userIdentity": {
    ​​
    "type": "IAMUser",
    "principalId": "ANONYMIZED",
    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/terraformops",
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "accessKeyId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "userName": "terraformops"
}​​,
"eventTime": "2021-02-02T18:12:19Z",
"eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "GetBucketWebsite",
"awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
"sourceIPAddress": "X.Y.Z.W",
"userAgent": "[aws-sdk-go/1.36.28 (go1.15.5; linux; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.14.4 (+https://www.terraform.io)]",
"errorCode": "NoSuchWebsiteConfiguration",
"errorMessage": "The specified bucket does not have a website configuration",
"requestParameters": {
    ​​
    "bucketName": "s3-bucket-name",
    "website": "",
    "Host": "s3-bucket-name.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
}
```

Why can't I use an existing S3 bucket as a data source within Terraform ? I don't treat it as a website anywhere in the terraform project so I don't know why it asks the server the GetBucketWebsite call and fail. Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why it asks the server the GetBucketWebsite call and fail.

It asks `GetBucketWebsite` as data source [aws_s3_bucket](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket) returns this information by providing `website_endpoint` and `website_domain`.

So you need to have permissions to call this action on the bucket. The error message suggests that the IAM user/role which you use for querying the bucket does not have all permissions to get needed information.

Comment: From what I can tell and have been told the user arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/terraformops has full access to S3.
I don't understand why Terraform calls GetBucketWebsite to a simple bucket with no website configured. Could this stem from a problem somewhere in S3 configuration/permissions ?

Comment: @ACloudEngineer Do you have any other user/role which you can double check this? Is the issue limited to only `terraformops` user? Or maybe you can check with AWS CLI? Can you use CLI to get this info using same user?